# Is it possible to divide an equilateral triangle into 16 congruent triangles?

Tags: polygons

The 16 triangles must all be congruent, and must not have overlapping sides.

Comment: It is possible to divide an equilateral triangle into 16 congruent triangles. What do you mean by "overlapping sides"?

Comment: If you arrange the small triangles like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/T_63R5zhVJfJR8bEkTuZaC-LwH1IAuOzRSOXxogzhAia7eib9q9g1j0MsUHjgvsWvPOPiiWl5EVGcnfts48pf7p3SMy5fuRDeuA), you can get a large equilateral triangle

Answer (score 1):

Here it is............................[image]